# Google People API authentication from Delphi

Tags: delphi, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I'm trying to upgrade an old application from using Google's contacts API to use Google's People API.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/contacts-api-migration?hl=en_US), I should use the following URL to authenticate: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts?ClientID=\](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts?ClientID=%5C)<ClientID>&ClientSecret=<ClientSecret>, but it only returns "contact" to me, no matter what I put into the ClientID and ClientSecret

So now I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Have you followed this guide https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/js?hl=en_US ?  Btw, the URL you quoted returns "contacts" rather than "contact".

Comment: I've tried, but it didn't help me much. Since I'm forced to use an very old version of Delphi, my rask is compared to make auth trough Postman

Comment: Which part of the documentation are you quoting? The page you referred to which has that URL is for the old Contacts (vs People) API, which was sunsetted in June. [This](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/contacts?hl=en_US) seems to refer to retrieving contacts using the People API.

Comment: I used to call https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token with ClientID etc. And now i need to contact the People API. But I  con not fint the new url

Comment: @DaveNottage:  Sorry, my bad.